# Error retrieving token ASP.NET Web API template iis 7.5 404 not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I’m working with a project that has been created as a ASP.Net Web Application with the ‘Web API’ template and ‘Individual User Accounts’ enabled as the authentication option. I have a console application that consumes the web api. But When I want to get the token it gives me a complete html string with "404 not found" in stead of a json array. What am I doing wrong?

This is mij console app code:

```
using ConsoleApplication1.Helpers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string userName = "user@user.com";
        const string password = "Password01!";
        const string apiBaseUri = "http://localhost/WebAPITest";
        const string apiGetPeoplePath = "/api/people";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Get the token
            var token = GetAPIToken(userName, password, apiBaseUri).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Token: {0}", token);

            //Make the call
            var response = GetRequest(token, apiBaseUri, apiGetPeoplePath).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("response: {0}", response);

            //wait for key press to exit
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetAPIToken(string userName, string password, string apiBaseUri)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //setup client
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBaseUri);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                //setup login data
                var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", userName),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
                });

                //send request
                HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsync("/Token", formContent);

                //get access token from response body
                var responseJson = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var jObject = JObject.Parse(responseJson);
                return jObject.GetValue("access_token").ToString();
            }
        }

        static async Task<string> GetRequest(string token, string apiBaseUri, string requestPath)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //setup client
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBaseUri);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

                //make request
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestPath);
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return responseString;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Startup.Auth:

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {   
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

    }
```

Comment: I would say that since it appears that you are in dev mode you need to make sure that your web app can be reached/requested on the uri you specify: "http://localhost/WebAPITest";

Comment: Hi DaniDev yes the Web app is reachable. I checked it via the browser. Anything that I can check?

Comment: I think the problem is not necessarily in the code it's a permission issue(?)
I would start by eliminating the simplest possible causes.
Bear in mind that you being able to browse the web App doesn't been that your console App is operating under the same user(identity). Most probably it isn't!
then if you have eliminated those causes then start looking at the code

Comment: I'm running everything locally. I am logged in as administrator on my development machine. I don't think it has to do something with permission.

Comment: Well if you have eliminated those issues, it seems like the problem is how  the route is formatted. Without seeing any of your web API interface it's hard to figure it out. You have to step through the code and see the route being submitted.

Comment: Hi DaniDev, please check my answer again. I have updated it with the Startup.Auth code. Can you see what's wrong?

Comment: Hi DaniDev in development when I use the iisexpres of vs 2015 I get the access token. But when I deploy it to the iis it doesn't work anymore. Do you have an idea what I can do to make it work?

Comment: hmmm, that is interesting It sounded from what you were saying and as I would have expected that it would be the other way around.
Like I said it sounds like: the request route/path (url) that you have hard coded in Console App is not matching up with your WebApi deployment.
You have to step through the code and try to see where exactly GetAPIToken() is requesting the token. 
Hope this makes sense. I don't think I can help you otherwise/

Comment: can you verify that the WebApi is reachable? If so what is the URI under which it is reachable?

Comment: Yes the url is reachable on http://localhost/WebAPITest. I have tried this: [iisappconfig](http://stevemichelotti.com/resolve-404-in-iis-express-for-put-and-delete-verbs/). But also not working. When I use a rest api tool it works fine. Only in C# client (console app) it does not.

Comment: reachable from one environment and not another: sounds like either permission/access issue.

Comment: No it's on the same machine with the same credentials. The only difference is that with iisexpress it works but on iis 7.5 it does not. But in both situations it works with a rest api tool. But with the c# client it onky works in iisexpress. I don't think it has to do with permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days thinking and trying. I found a solution that worked for me. In my previous code it worked only in iisexpress (I don't know why so if someone knows please share!). But in my new code it worked for both iisexpress and iis 7.5.

```
using ConsoleApplication1.Helpers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    const string userName = "user@user.com";
    const string password = "Password01!";
    const string apiBaseUri = "http://localhost/WebAPITest";

    private static async void GetAPIToken()
    {
       string responseJson =  await ResponseAsStringAsync(string.Format("{0}/token", apiBaseUri),
            new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", userName),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
            });

        var jObject = JObject.Parse(responseJson);
        string token = jObject.GetValue("access_token").ToString();            
    }

    public static async Task<string> ResponseAsStringAsync(string url, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postData)
    {
        string responseString = string.Empty;

        var uri = new Uri(url);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData))
        {
            content.Headers.Clear();
            content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

            responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        return responseString;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetAPIToken();           
        Console.ReadKey();
    }



}


}
```

I hope it helps someone else with the same problem.

Comment: So what was it that made it start working? From your answer it looks like you just found other code that was working (copy/paste) but didn't figure out what was really causing the issue in the first place.